# How to call the method in watchkit extension from parent ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

We can call the method  `openParentApplication:reply:` in parent ios app from watch kit extension.

But is there any way to call the method in watchkit extension from parent ios app ?

For example:In my app when user add event in ios app then watchkit event list also should refresh so for that i need to call the refresh method in watchkit extension when user add new event in main app.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly call a method from watchkit extension, but you can send a darwin notification (or use `MMWormhole` library ([here](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole)), and execute proper method after recieving it.

Comment: Great Answer! Though, I would like to add that this isn't documented as Supported. This may be prevented in the future or it may not pass apple certification when they start accepting watchkit apps. Though, for now it works splendidly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in **WatchConnectivity** framework to send message from iOS app to the paired Apple Watch.

1) First, activate watch connectivity session **both** in iOS app and WatchKit extension. On the iOS side it can be done in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of the app delegate. On watch side you can run this code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method of the WatchKit extension delegate.

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
  let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
  session.delegate = self
  session.activateSession()
}
```

2) Now send a message from your iOS app.

```
let session = WCSession.defaultSession()

session.sendMessage(["message from iOS app":""], replyHandler: { reply in
  // Handle reply from watch (optional)      
}, errorHandler: nil)
```

3) Receive the message in your WatchKit extension by implementing the `session didReceiveMessage` method in your `WCSessionDelegate` delegate class.

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
  if let message = message["message from iOS app"] { 
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("myapp.reload", object: self, userInfo: ["data": message])
  }
}
```

Upon receiving the message from iOS we are sending a notification with `postNotificationName` method.

4) Subscribe to this notification in your InterfaceController that needs updating (or anywhere else where you want to receive this update notification).

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
  super.awakeWithContext(context)

  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "didReceiveReloadNotification:", name: "myapp.reload", object: nil)
}

deinit {
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self,
  name: "myapp.reload", object: nil)
}
```

5) Finally, implement the notification handler method. This is where you can update your UI.

```
func didReceiveReloadNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
  let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String: String]
  if let userInfo = userInfo, data = userInfo["data"] {
    // Update UI
  }
}
```

Note: for the sake of readability I am using inline text string for the  notification name "myapp.reload" and the message key "message from iOS app". But in the real app it is better to use properties for these text strings to avoid typos.